# Can I conclude that $x=f(x)$ from the assumption that $f(x)=f(f(x))$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If given $$f(x)=f(f(x))$$ would it be correct to cancel one function on both sides and end up with $$x=f(x)$$ if $f(x)$ is an injective function? If saying this is incorrect, please could someone explain why? Sorry if this is a stupid question but I can't find an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Apply the definition of injectivity $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$ with $y = f(x)$ and you'll see that you argument is correct.

Comment: I see - thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write it down from definitions. If $f$ is injective, then this means, by **definition**, that

$$\forall x_1, x_2\in D_f: f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2.$$

Now, set $x_1=x$ and $x_2=f(x)$. What does the above expression change into?

Answer (score 1):

It is true. Think about definition of injective function.